# iOS - Israel has weekdays from Sunday - Thursday. How can I account for this?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization

I'm getting many emails from Israeli users of my app complaining that their weekdays are different to most other countries, and my app doesn't reflect that.

Unfortunately `[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]` doesn't seem to change from it's value of '1' when the region is set to Israel ('1' denoting 'Monday' in a Sunday to Saturday calendar environment as shown by NSDateForamtter's `standaloneWeekdaySymbols` method.).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to find a localised first day of the week?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an iOS design bug of some kind. Setting the first day does not influence which days are the weekend.

Just checked on my wife's iPhone. It's set to Hebrew and Israel locale. Under settings, checked mail, contact and calendar. First week day is set to Sunday (default) as it should.

In the iOS calendar app, the first day **is** Sunday, but it is marked as part of the weekend (greyed out). As Israel is the only country I know where the weekend is Friday-Saturday, this is a bug.

Wife is running iOS 9.1 on iPhone 6.

=======================================================================

And here's a screenshot from my own phone running iOS 8.x.
Note the Hebrew dates below the Gregorian ones and the fact the week starts with a grey number.

[image]

Comment: So you're saying - basically, there's nothing in iOS that covers this, and in fact Apple's own calendar app shows the incorrect weekend days in Israel? Wow